# jQuery, regex that matches a query string

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this URL and I want to match the **test=dahsdhajd** part in order to remove it using replace();

```
http://www.mysite.com?test=dhasjdhja&src=list
```

I could use this regex:

```
var regex = /test=.+&/;
var url = window.location.href;
var newUrl = url.replace(regex, "");
```

This would work just fine, giving me:

```
http://www.mysite.com?test=dhasjdhja
```

The problem is, I need to make the regex match the **test = dshajdhajd** when I do not have another query string after it:

```
http://www.mysite.com?test=dhasjdhja
```

**My current regex won't match the above, because there is no "&"**
Also, in this case, I need a way to remove the question mark also - so the regex should match it too.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest working with the character behind it, like so:

```
.replace(/([?&])test(?:(?=&)|=[^&]*)/,"$1")
```

This works fine with the end of the string, and allows it to not affect something like `?anothertest=derp`

EDIT: Changed it a bit to add support for an empty or boolean parameter.

Comment: In a perfect world, we'd use `/(?<[?&)test=[^&]+/` and replace with `""` but sadly JavaScript has no lookbehind assertions...

Comment: Ty very much, I have made an edit - I should remove the question mark aslo, when there isn't a second parameter

Comment: That's not required, the question mark is harmless, but you can chain an additional `.replace(/?$/,'')` to remove the question mark if it is left on its own.

Comment: Yes but then, I'd need another check to see when to apply the additional replace

Comment: No you don't. Just chain the replace normally. If the `?` is not at the end of the string, nothing will happen to it.

Comment: One more thing, I have tested it, but it's won't match the & - so it won't match test=dsada&